# Followup: G1 Collector not doing full GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

This is followup question to [G1 Collector not doing full GC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555796/g1-collector-not-doing-full-gc)

Removed 
`-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=80`

Default for IHOP is 45%

`S0C S1C S0U S1U EC EU   OC    OU    PC   PU    YGC  YGCT  FGC FGCT   GCT`

`0 96M 0 96M 3.4G  704M  6.5G  5.5G 640M 451.2M 6739  44.4m 0   0m   44.4m`

Old generation is reaching 5.5G in size still full GC is not happening.
Any idea why?

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: enable GC logging, post a log

Comment: $1 = gc_2016-08-05.log.  `echo "Application time line count"
grep -ac "Application time" $1  727,240  

echo "stopped line count"
grep -ac "were stopped" $1  727,241  

echo "Total lines"
wc -l $1  1,479,213

egrep -av 'Application time|were stopped' $1 > other_lines.txt`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sameergn/0935a0f50a62eb7f350975d8d2dacd40  https://gist.github.com/sameergn/ba0bd3c1a2eec5cd1e7266c710f9de95

Comment: @the8472 gc log mostly contains "Application time" and "were stopped" lines. Hence copied remaining lines to other_lines.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G1 seems to be working as it should. The average pause times of 763 young collections was 163ms, well within the 200ms default pause goal.

The longest pause was 373ms, of which 279.2ms were spent on reference processing. `-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled` should help here.

> Default for IHOP is 45%

When none is set that's the *initial* IHOP, but it gets dynamically adjusted at runtime to meet other GC goals.

Comment: No Full GC is a good thing, but it is resulting in too much young collection times. If we invoke a full GC manually then you can see that eden gets more space as old space goes down from 4.5G to 2.4G. https://gist.github.com/sameergn/18f4c9197701261f338bfb1eafa328a8 With 1.6, we had 5G for Eden and 5G for old, and old generation objects used to starve for space, now it is opposite.